# Find phrase that has a specific length and is composed by certain letters

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Suppose I have a list of 1 million words. I have the length of the phrase that I need to find, and I know that this word can be composed of at most 3 other words, for example `Queen of England`, has 14 letters, and the letters are `adeeefglnnnoqu`.

The problem is that, given a dictionary that big, first I'd have to search for the first word, which could have anything from 1 to 14 letters, then for the second word (if the first one doesn't have 14 letters), then the third word.

Given a dictionary size of 1 million words, the first loop would have to loop through all of them, then the second one also needs to loop through all 1 million words, because it has to eliminate the letters that were consumed by the first word, and loop through all the 1 million words for the ones that are still valid without the letters that the first word consumed. The third loop would be a little easier, since I know the exact length of the word (`14 - word1.length - word2.length`).

That's at the very least, only considering the first 2 loops, 1,000,000,000,000 iterations. Is there a better way to do this?

This question is language agnostic, since I don't really care about what language I need to use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed up the process by filtering out the words that clearly do not belong, i.e. the words that have letters *not* found in the phrase. Once you pre-filter the 1M list, you should end up with much shorter sub-list. Running your algorithm on that sub-list should be significantly faster, since it's an `O(N^2)` algorithm: even if you narrow down the list to ten percent of the words (I expect you to get much fewer words than that) you'd get a 100-fold improvement. It is OK for list to have "false positives", as long as potential matches are not thrown away.

Here is how you can do the pre-filtering: for each word, build its "signature", a 26-bit number with a bit set for each letter present in the word at least once (letters are numbered 0 through 25, ignoring the case). For example, the word `"Queen"` would have a signature with bits 4, 13, 16, and 20 set to one.

Now construct a signature for your three-word phrase, and use it to filter the list of 1M words: if a bitwise `OR` of the word's signature and the phrase's signature equals the phrase's signature, keep the word; otherwise, throw it away.

Your filtered list should be much shorter, so your `O(N^2)` algorithm should run much faster.